# Including submodules without entire modules with PyInstaller

Tags: pyinstaller, auto-py-to-exe

I'm turning some of my work into EXEs to be distributed amongst my colleagues, and before doing so I'd prefer to slim down the EXE that PyInstaller is coming out with. I'm currently using Auto-Py-To-Exe, but would be fine doing it in CLI. How would I go about importing matplotlib.pyplot, without including the entirety of matplotlib? I first tried including `--exclude-module matplotlib` and `--hidden-import matplotlib.pyplot` but that didn't work, and I got error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'` upon running the EXE.

Comment: if you want to use matplotlib then your going to want to bundle it with the exe.